# Fast way to compare a specific nibble in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, performance

I have a mask and a number. The mask consists of nibbles having the value 0xf and one nibble which contains the bits which I have to compare. 0xf means "these bits are not relevant while comparing". **Examples:**

```
1111 1111 0011 1111 (Mask)
xxxx xxxx 0010 xxxx (Number)
Result: Not Equal since 3dec != 2dec


1111 1111 0011 1111 (Mask)
xxxx xxxx 0011 xxxx (Number)
Result: Equal since 3dec == 3dec
```

The position of the relevant nibble may be anywhere within the mask. **Example:**

```
0110 1111 1111 1111 (Mask)
0110 xxxx xxxx xxxx (Number)
Result: Equal since 6dec == 6dec
```

I played around with ~, ^, & etc. but I could not identify an easy way to get a "true" or "false". Is there any solution **without shifting** or comparing nibble per nibble?

Comment: For the record, those are called "nibbles".

Comment: *hint* use hamming weight. there are fast builtins (usually called popcount)

Comment: Suppose you wish to compare only the 3rd nibble, but in that nibble the value you want is 0xF. Are you excluding that case?

Comment: Yes, this case is excluded. Each nibble in "number" can reach from 0 to 9 (BCD). I forgot to mention that fact. I will have a look at the proposed solutions tomorrow

Comment: Are the `x`s in `number` actual bits that we don't care about?  Or is number just a nybble value that you would have to shift to align with the nybble of interest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have noted, you don't realy have a mask; you have a vector of nybbles that you want to compare, with the nybble 0xf meaning "don't care".  So the first step is to figure out the actual mask of what to compare and ignore:

```
uint64_t dont_care = ((mask & 0x7777777777777777ULL) + 0x1111111111111111ULL) & mask;
dont_care &= 0x8888888888888888ULL;
dont_care |= dont_care >> 1;
dont_care |= dont_care >> 2;
```

This computes a true mask -- each nybble of `dont_care` will be 0xf if the `mask` nybble was 0xf and 0 otherwise.  Note that this only needs to be done ONCE for each `mask` value.  It also assumes a 64-bit (16 nybble) mask -- a smaller mask can use smaller types/constants.

Now you can test the mask simply:

```
if ((number | dont_care) == mask) { ...
```

An alternate way of computing `dont_care` is:

```
uint64_t dont_care = mask & (mask << 1);
dont_care &= dont_care << 2;
dont_care &= 0x8888888888888888ULL;
dont_care |= dont_care >> 1;
dont_care |= dont_care >> 2;
```

which may be faster on some machines (uses fewer large constants, but more shifts, which are slow on some CPUs).  If you really care, you can profile both methods to see which is faster for your machine.

Yet another possibility:

```
uint64_t dont_care = mask & (mask >> 1);
dont_care &= dont_care >> 2;
dont_care &= 0x1111111111111111ULL;
dont_care *= 15;
```

Comment: A very nice solution (I am using your first approach)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is occurring because your mask is not really a mask.  It's both a mask *and* a "Flag".  If you separate these...

```
0000 0000 1111 0000 (Mask)
0000 0000 0011 0000 (Flag)
xxxx xxxx 0010 xxxx (Number)
```

Then the math becomes super easy!

```
if (Number&Mask == Flag)
```

---

I doubt that there is a way to do this without comparing one nibble at a time, the use of `0xF`as a special flag makes all standard operations useless to you.

---

I figured I ought to come up with a working expression at least, even if it violates the "nibble at a time" part.

```
if (((Mask&0xF000)!=0xF000 && (Mask&0xF000)!=(Number&0xF000)) ||
    ((Mask&0x0F00)!=0x0F00 && (Mask&0x0F00)!=(Number&0x0F00)) ||
    ((Mask&0x00F0)!=0x00F0 && (Mask&0x00F0)!=(Number&0x00F0)) ||
    ((Mask&0x00F0)!=0x000F && (Mask&0x000F)!=(Number&0x000F)))
{
    std::cout << "fail\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "pass\n";
}

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8317f68c396802e0
```

I won't claim this is the fastest way, but at least it's accurate, and ought to be fairly fast since those operations are all fast and independent, with several duplicates that any half-decent optimizer ought to notice.

Comment: Sure, any problem is solvable if you can just change the problem. I think it's more interesting to take on the problem as stated in the question.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, A bit can't store three different values. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For each bit of the number,

- Its value can be anything to pass (which you denoted by "x").
- Its value must be 0 to pass (which you denoted by "0").
- Its value must be 1 to pass (which you denoted by "1").

You need more than one bit of information per bit in the number.

This is often done using two numbers as big as your number. One's the mask, and the other is the desired value.

If you want to check for

```
xxxx xxxx 0010 xxxx
```

you need

```
mask = 0x00F0;
flag = 0x0020;

( num & mask ) == flag
```

---

Technically, since you always compare 4 bits, you could encode the information you want in fewer bits than `num`.

```
data = 1 << 4 | 0x2;  // 1 is the nibble offset, 0x2 is the flag.

shift = ( data >> 4 ) * 4;
mask = 0xF << shift;
flag = ( data & 0xF ) << shift;

( num & mask ) == flag
```

Comment: You are correct that extra bits of information are required. However that information is encoded in the rule: A nybble of 0xf is a mask and any other value is a match test.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, I know it can be encoded in a rule, because I already demonstrated that. Your rule is wrong, though. You also need to know which nibble to match. `xxxx xxxx 0010 xxxx` is not the same thing as `xxxx 0010 xxxx xxxx`. The minimum number of bits is `num_size_in_bits / 4 + 4`. Using this minimal number of bits is demonstrated below the divider in my answer. I'm not sure why you're giving me this incorrect and redundant information. (Or why it got two votes!)

Comment: I'm giving you this information because you're making an incorrect assertion. 32 bits is enough information, since when combined with the rule it's sufficient to derive both the `mask` and the `flag`.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, I know. I said 12 bits is enough for 32-bit numbers, and I showed how to do that. So why do you keep telling me things I've already said!? Did you even read my answer?

Comment: I was responding to a comment you left on a different answer stating "a bit can't store three different values". This point is the one you make at the beginning of your answer. I merely wanted to point out that it's not necessary to store three different values per bit. If you already understood that, why make it so prominent in your answer?

Comment: That said, only 7 bits are needed. `ceil(log2(num_size_in_bits / 4)) + 4` is the correct formula.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, Re "why make it so prominent in your answer?" The explanation of why it's impossible to do what the OP asked? Why wouldn't it be?! It can't be done using a mask.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to check if answer has some wrong ones:

```
Mask: 1111 1010

Val:  xxxx 1100

................. or

Res:  1111 1110

Mask == Val ? false
```

Second example:

```
Mask: 1111 1010

Val:  xxxx 1010

................. or

Res:  1111 1010

Mask == Val ? true //- maybe true (there may be some wrong zeros :( )
```

It is only party solved. Now is harder part. You have to check if there are any wrong zeros

For performance the first part of algorithm may look:

```
if( (mask | val)  != mask ) 
    return false;
else
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are guaranteed that there is exactly one nybble in your mask which is not `1111`, yes?  (If that's not true, the problem is unsolvable.)

Most processors nowadays have an instruction called "count leading zeroes" or "find first set bit" or something like that, which can be used to locate the nybble that's not all-ones.  You can then use that to construct a mask for the "relevant" nybble.  Off the top of my head, TOTALLY UNTESTED, making use of GCC's intrinsic [`__builtin_clz`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins) (sorry, no direct link available, you'll have to search in the page) that accesses this instruction:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>
bool
test_val_against_mask(uint32_t val, uint32_t mask)
{
    int first_zero_from_top = __builtin_clz(~mask);
    uint32_t relevant_nybble =
        ((uint32_t) 0xF) << (((32 - first_zero_from_top) + 3) & ~3);

    /* This will not work correctly if there is more than one nybble in 'mask'
       that has any cleared bits.  */
    assert((mask & ~relevant_nybble) == ~relevant_nybble);

    return (val & relevant_nybble) == (mask & relevant_nybble);
}
```

If this doesn't work, it's probably because the calculation of `relevant_nybble` is wrong; please let me know and I'll debug it.

Comment: As added on top: Yes, the case is "1111" is excluded. Each nibble in "number" can reach from 0 to 9 (BCD)

Comment: @Anonymous I understood that.  The question is whether there can be *more than one* nybble *in the mask* that is other than 1111.  My solution assumes that that never happens (see added assertion).

Comment: No, there can not be more than one within the mask